# HackerEarth Question solution failing for the input testcase

Tags: java

Below hackerearth qn has been asked in one of coding qns

**Farthest from zero**

You are given an integer array A of size N.

**Task**
Write a program to print the farthest element from 0.
If there are multiple elements, print the number with the least value.

**Input format**

- The first line contains a single integer N denoting the size of the
  array A.
- The next line contains N integers denoting the elements of    the
  array A.

**Output format**

Print the farthest element from 0.

**Sample input 1**

5

1 2 3 4 5

**Sample Output1**

5

**Solution prepared by me:**

```
public static farthestfromzero(int N, int [] Arr) {
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
          ts.add(Arr[i]);
    } 
  return ts.last();
}
```

> **Ask**: This solution worked for me for the initial scenario, but when I
> submitted it , it didn't worked.

Comment: What is ```O```(o), the question said the farthest number from ```O```(o), is it just 0(zero)?

Comment: @lierwu yes I think so, since the heading of the question was "farthest from zero"

Comment: why is it ```t.last?```? Do you mean ```ts.last();```?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this particular coding challenge -- do you know the input they attempted to pass your code? Or is there an indication of why it failed -- eg that you ran out of memory or something? That would've been my bet, of course, since you could have just iterated through the array in order, tracking the farthest number found and then returned at the end, instead of trying to build out a tree ...

Comment: yes its is ts.last(), updated it

Comment: @ASharma7 Your code does not work when negative numbers are involved (like `-4 5`)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas the final input was in testcase, input was hidden , so dont know what went wrong. It might be the issue because of  memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the tree set is sorted by the values, the number can be begtive. So... I think it should be this:

```
public static int farthestfromzero(int N, int [] Arr) {
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
          ts.add(Arr[i]);
    } 
  int maxV = ts.last();
  int minV = ts.first();
  
  if(Math.abs(minV) >= maxV){
      return minV;
  }
  return maxV;

}
```

Also if it's memory exceed, then try this:

```
    public static int farthestfromzero(int N, int [] Arr) {//You don't really need to store every elements
        int best = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
            if(Math.abs(Arr[i]) > Math.abs(best)) {
                best = Arr[i];
            }else if(Math.abs(best) == Math.abs(Arr[i]) && best > Arr[i]) {
                best = Arr[i];
            }
        }
        return best;    
    }
```

Comment: Small hint: you can save 2 lines of code by using `>=`

Comment: lierwu I have one more qn from Qn from the test, Please have a look, uploading direct screenshot in another Qn

Comment: @lierwu please have a look at this one as well : https://stackoverflow.com/q/65115526/4860775

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm does not account for negative integers.

Consider this array:

`[-10, 7, 5, 1]`

Which number is furthest from zero?
Which will your algorithm pick?

Also note, this requirement:

> If there are multiple elements, print the number with the least value.

So, from an array like this:

`[-10, 1, 2 ,10]`

You need to pick -10, and not 10.

Comment: @lierwu that's because you put in the effort to produce actual code! That's a good thing!

Comment: thanks to both of you for pointing out this thing, accepting lier wu since he gave code as well

Comment: @LevM. Plesae have a look at this one -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/65115526/4860775

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer. I just wrote the core logic. Please add the basic condition check. Also, I did it in Python3.
Commented code the expansion of the below single line code.

```
A1 = sorted(A)
print(A1[0]) if (abs(A1[0])> abs(A1[-1])) else print(A1[-1]) if (abs(A1[0]) < abs(A1[-1])) else print(A1[0])

# if (abs(A1[0])== abs(A1[-1])): 
#     print(A1[0])
# else:
#     if(abs(A1[0]) > abs(A1[-1])):
#         print(A1[0])
#     else:
#         print(A1[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a function in JAVA that returns lesser maximum value element if there are any duplicates.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static int farthestFromZero(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.abs(arr[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {

        if(arr[i] > max && arr[i] != arr[i+1]){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to find the element which is far from 0 considering both +ve and -ve values in an array.

My idea is to just push the forthmost element to the last position of an array.

Sample Inputs and Outputs:

Input: int[] arr = new int[] { -100, 90, -80, 500, -2, 50 };

Output: 500

Input: int[] arr = new int[] { -100, 90, 80, 50, -200, 2 };

Output: -200

```
private static int getForthMostWithoutSorting(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            int curEle = a[i];
            if (curEle < 0) {
                curEle = -a[i];
            }
            int nextEle = a[i + 1];
            if (nextEle < 0) {
                nextEle = -a[i + 1];
            }
            if (curEle > nextEle) {
                int temporary = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temporary;
            }
        }
        return a[a.length - 1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FarthestFromZero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10 };
        boolean flag = true;
        TreeSet<Integer> toTreeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        for (Integer eachVal : input) {

            if (!toTreeSet.contains(eachVal)) {
                
                toTreeSet.add(eachVal);
                
            } else {

                flag = false;
            }

        }

        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("No duplicate values in array: " + toTreeSet.last());
        } else {

            System.out.println("it has duplicate values in array: " + toTreeSet.first());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is a bug in here. Try with [-1, 1, 1, 10]. Also, there is another answer that solves it similarly to how you've done it so my take would be that you should comment on the other one if you want to add more details. You'll need more reputation though to be able to comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29792155)

Answer (score 0):

The farthest element from 0 can be on the negative side or positive side of a number line.

You need to sort it using `Arrays.sort(arr)` This method internally uses the dual-pivot quicksort method which has the time complexity of `O(nlog(n))` and obviously constant space complexity. Then compare the absolute value of first and last element and return the larger one.

```
private static int findFarthest(int[] arr) {
     int N = arr.length;
     Arrays.sort(arr);
     if (Math.abs(arr[0]) > Math.abs(arr[N-1]))
         return arr[0];
     else
         return arr[N-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {-7, -9, 5, 3, 1, 2, 9, 10, 15};
    int farthest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(arr[i]) >= Math.abs(farthest)){
           if(Math.abs(arr[i]) == Math.abs(farthest)){
               farthest = arr[i] < farthest ? arr[i]  : farthest ;
           }else {
               farthest = arr[i];
           }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(farthest);
}
```